# Java - Lock Aspect Ratio of JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jframe

Is it possible to lock the aspect ratio of a JFrame in Java Swing?

For example, if my window is 200px by 200px, and the user wants to resize it, I want the ratio between the width and the height at 1:1, so that if the new width is 400px, the new height is forced to 400px.

I'm aware of `ComponentListener` and `componentResized`, but I'm having difficulty not getting it to go into an infinite loop of resizing, because I'm resizing the window in a resize listener.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a specific answer to your question, but I have often found that the way to avoid the "infinite loop of resizing" you talk about is to defer your call to resize the window:

```
boolean correctAspectRatio = ...; // check to see if new size meets aspect ratio requirements

if (!correctAspectRatio) {
  final Frame _frame = this;
  final int _width = ...; // calculated width
  final int _height = ...; // calculated height

  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
      _frame.setSize(_width, _height);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Even if I do this, it will still go into a loop of resizing, it's just not as noticeable. Try doing _width + 20, _height + 20, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I am assuming you don't call the resize if the size meets the aspect ratio, right? See my edited answer

Comment: Ah, that worked great. I suppose there really isn't much of a way to do this while the user is resizing, but this way works fine. Thanks.